# How to address multiple API end points using Retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

In my Android project I am using the following [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) `ApiModule` for **one** API end point. Please note, I use [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) for injecting dependencies.

```
@Module(
        complete = false,
        library = true
)
public final class ApiModule {

    public static final String PRODUCTS_BASE_URL = "https://products.com";

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Endpoint provideEndpoint() {
        return Endpoints.newFixedEndpoint(PRODUCTS_BASE_URL);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
            PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    RestAdapter provideRestAdapter(
        Endpoint endpoint, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
                .setEndpoint(endpoint)
                .setConverter(new JacksonConverter(objectMapper))
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ProductsService provideProductsService(RestAdapter restAdapter) {
        return restAdapter.create(ProductsService.class);
    }

}
```

Now, there is **another API** (e.g. `"http://subsidiaries.com"`) which I want to communicate with. Is it possible to extend the given `ApiModule` while reusing the `ObjectMapper` and the `RestAdapter`? Or should I not extend it? I already tried to duplicate the module. But this involves that I have to duplicate the `Endpoint`, `ObjectMapper` and ... the `RestAdapter` has a **private** contructor - so I can't.

Comment: can't you make a constructor of `ApiModule ` and pass the end point there and code accordingly with IF condition in all methods?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Dependency injection uses the **default constructor**. Therefore, passing parameters to manually handle different cases does not help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could work with `Named` annotations:

```
@Module(
        complete = false,
        library = true
)
public final class ApiModule {

    public static final String PRODUCTS_BASE_URL = "https://products.com";
    public static final String SUBSIDIARIES_BASE_URL = "https://subsidiaries.com";

    public static final String PRODUCTS = "products";
    public static final String SUBSIDIARIES = "subsidiaries";

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(PRODUCTS)
    Endpoint provideProductsEndpoint() {
        return Endpoints.newFixedEndpoint(PRODUCTS_BASE_URL);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(SUBSIDIARIES)
    Endpoint provideSubsidiariesEndpoint() {
        return Endpoints.newFixedEndpoint(SUBSIDIARIES_BASE_URL);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
            PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(PRODUCTS)
    RestAdapter provideProductsRestAdapter(@Named(PRODUCTS) Endpoint endpoint, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return newRestAdapterBuilder(objectMapper)
                .setEndpoint(endpoint)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(SUBSIDIARIES)
    RestAdapter provideSubsidiariesRestAdapter(@Named(SUBSIDIARIES) Endpoint endpoint, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return newRestAdapterBuilder(objectMapper)
                .setEndpoint(endpoint)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(PRODUCTS)
    ProductsService provideProductsService(@Named(PRODUCTS) RestAdapter restAdapter) {
        return restAdapter.create(ProductsService.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(SUBSIDIARIES)
    ProductsService provideSubsidiariesService(@Named(SUBSIDIARIES) RestAdapter restAdapter) {
        return restAdapter.create(ProductsService.class);
    }

    private RestAdapter.Builder newRestAdapterBuilder(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                       .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
                       .setConverter(new JacksonConverter(objectMapper));
    }
}
```

Now everywhere where you inject `ProductsService` you need to either annotate the dependency with `@Named(PRODUCTS)` or `@Named(SUBSIDIARIES)`, depending on which variant you need. Of course instead of the `@Named` annotations you could also create your own, custom annotations and use them. See [here](http://square.github.io/dagger/) under "Qualifiers".

To flatten your module a bit you could move the creation of the RestAdapters into the `provide*Service()` methods and get rid of the `provide*RestAdapter()` methods. Unless you need the RestAdapters as a dependency outside of the module, of course.