# Retrofit - Multiple endpoints with same RestAdapter

Tags: android, retrofit

I would like to know how to create a RestAdapter that can switch between two endpoints. Currently in my app, the RestAdapter is created in the Application class(singleton). I am looking for a way to have different endpoints without actually creating multiple RestAdapter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Endpoint is called for every request. If you want to switch on an algorithm you can implement your own (e.g., to do round-robin). Other than that, a single RestAdapter is tied to an Endpoint, you cannot control it on a per-method basis or anything. - Jake Wharton

So I created different rest adapters for the different endpoints I use in my app.

Answer (score 8):

Retrofit 1 calls Endpoint for each request (no cache), to you just need to extend Retrofit.Endpoint with some setter and pass this Endpoint when your creating the RestAdapter :

```
Endpoint mDynamicEndpoint = new DynamicEndpoint("http://firstdomain.fr");
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(mDynamicEndpoint)
    .build();

mDynamicEndpoint.setBaseUrl("http://yourdomain.com");
```

Possible duplicate : [Dynamic Paths in Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279006/dynamic-paths-in-retrofit)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a map from endpoint to RestAdapter. You would wind up with one adapter for each domain. Not a great solution if you have a lot of endpoints.

I believe the DynamicEndpoint solution above could lead to race conditions if two requests to different endpoints were fired at the same time.