# Replace common path parameters in retrofit 2 with okhttp

Tags: android, okhttp, retrofit2

I have some service urls with the same baseUrl. For some urls there will be some common used parameters, for example an `apiVersion` or `locale`. But they don't have to be in every url, so I can't add them to the baseUrl.

```
.../api/{apiVersion}/{locale}/event/{eventId}
.../api/{apiVersion}/{locale}/venues
.../api/{apiVersion}/configuration
```

I don't want to add these parameters in the retrofit interface. In retrofit 1, I made an interceptor and used `RequestFacade.addPathParam(..., ...)` to fill these common path parameters for every url.

For retrofit 2, I can't seem to find a proper way to do this with okhttp. The only way I see this being possible right now is to get the `HttpUrl` from `Chain.request().httpUrl();` in an okhttp `Interceptor` and manipulate that one myself, but I don't know if this is the best way to go.

Has anyone come across a better way to replace path parameters in an okhttp `Interceptor`?

*At the time of writing I'm using retrofit:2.0.0-beta2 and okhttp:2.7.2.*

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31002094 .

Comment: @mtotschnig there is no up to date answer(using OkHttp 3+ & Retrofit 2+) on that thread.

Comment: @Singed the answer I link to works for me with Retrofit2 and OkHttp 3

Comment: @mtotschnig oh sure, that works, but doesn't solve the problem. The problem is we have a retrofit interface with a lot of methods. We don't want to set path to each of them manually, we want to do it in one place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> For retrofit 2, I can't seem to find a proper way to do this with
>   okhttp. The only way I see this being possible right now is to get the
>   HttpUrl from Chain.request().httpUrl(); in an okhttp Interceptor and
>   manipulate that one myself, but I don't know if this is the best way
>   to go.

My implementation using okhttp:3.2

```
    class PathParamInterceptor implements Interceptor {
        private final String mKey;
        private final String mValue;

        private PathParamInterceptor(String key, String value) {
            mKey = String.format("{%s}", key);
            mValue = value;
        }

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();

            HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = originalRequest.url().newBuilder();
            List<String> segments = originalRequest.url().pathSegments();

            for (int i = 0; i < segments.size(); i++) {
                if (mKey.equalsIgnoreCase(segments.get(i))) {
                    urlBuilder.setPathSegment(i, mValue);
                }
            }

            Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .url(urlBuilder.build())
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This helped me. Getting the path segments and looping through them is safer, since the code won't break if the path segment ever changes.

Comment: I make it same but i have a problem. Retrofit call first witheout replace and then with the replaced..
Can you tell me why?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209066/retrofit2-put-token-in-url-with-placeholder

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use this way:

```
@GET("/api/{apiVersion}/{locale}/venues")
Call<FilterResponse> getLocaleVenues
          @Path("apiVersion") int apiVersion,
          @Path("locale") String locale
);
```

Hope it helps.