# Retrofit2 put token in URL with placeholder

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a Problem with replace the placeholder in the url with the auth-token.

My OkHttpClient:

```
OkHttpClient clientToken = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```

My TockenInspector:

```
private class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor{

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response mainResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        //Auth Data available?
        if(RestClient.this.isAuthenticationDataSet()){
            //Get Token
            String currentToken = getToken(RestClient.this.authCustomerNumber,
                    RestClient.this.authUser,
                    RestClient.this.authPassword,
                    RestClient.this.authDeviceId);

            //Original RequestData
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();
            HttpUrl originalUrl = originalRequest.url();
            List<String> urlSegments = originalUrl.pathSegments();

            //New URL
            boolean tokenFoundInSegments = false;
            HttpUrl.Builder newUrlBuilder = originalUrl.newBuilder();

            //Search token placeholders in url segments
            for(int i=0; i<urlSegments.size(); i++){
                String segment = urlSegments.get(i);

                if(segment.equals(tokenPlaceholder)){
                    segment = currentToken;
                    tokenFoundInSegments = true;
                }

                newUrlBuilder.setPathSegment(i, segment);
            }

            //If not found in segments: Set token as get param
            if(!tokenFoundInSegments){
                newUrlBuilder.addQueryParameter("token", currentToken);
            }

            HttpUrl url = newUrlBuilder.build();
            Request tokenRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder().url(url).build();

            return chain.proceed(tokenRequest);
        }else{
            //No auth data available
            return chain.proceed(chain.request());
        }
    }
}
```

My Call:

```
ObservableField<UserLoginData> userdata = 
UserBackend.getInstance(context).getUserLoginData();
//order the basket
Call<RestResult<BasketResult>> call = 
this.restAPIBasket.orderBasket(basket.getId(), userdata.get().getPassword());

call.enqueue(new Callback<RestResult<BasketResult>>() {
.....
```

URL:
    URL/R_token/password?format=json

My Problem:

when I debug, retrofit executes a call without setting the token and then does it go through the tokenInterceptor class and make the call again.
Can anyone help me to fix this Problem?
I can not always use the token as a query but in certain URLs only as a path

Answer (score 1):

The problem was: `Response mainResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());`

`chain.proceed()` make the call witheout set the token and the return with set the token. also calls twice. I removed the first and it's work correct